# Android Studio is creating my projects in Kotlin, not Java

Tags: android-studio

So, I just installed Android Studio for programming after a long time. I created a new project, but it is getting created in Kotlin language, and I want Java language. I tried everything on my side, but it still doesnt work. Please help, I'm new to all this stuff.

I tried changing JDK versions, path in Gradle, but still it isnt working.

Comment: I've noticed this too, but I didn't bother to try to figure out why. The `New -> Create Java Class` option isn't there either. I don't actually do Android development, I only use Android Studio to research questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: By default theres a Kotlin file, but I want the MainActivity.Java

Answer (score 0):

Depending which Android Studio version you are using, if you are creating a new project, just choose Java as the programming language:

[image]

If you have an already created project, as pointed out above, you should be able to choose Java Class instead of Kotlin

[image]

Comment: If you choose "Empty Activity" for the new project you don't get a choice for language.

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1**:

When some project already is opened:

`File` -> `New` -> `New Project...` -> `Basic Views Activity` -> set `Language` to the `Java` -> `Finish`

Or via Android Studio welcome screen:

`Basic Views Activity` -> set `Language` to the `Java` -> `Finish`